# Loop through corresponding rows and change value of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this csv file which has large amount of data. I have taken the csv as a dataframe in python. I want to compare each row with its corresponding row and if the first row has value 1 and second row has value 100 , then the program should replace 100 to 50. If there are 2 rows containing 1 above 100 , then the value of 100 should be changed to 25 , if 3 rows are there above 100 containing 1 ,  then the value of 100 should be 12.5 and so on.This is the dataframe of the csv file:

```
  rule_id           51594   51668   51147   51182   51447
0   comparison1     1.0      1.0     NaN    NaN      NaN
1   last_comp      100.0    100.0    NaN    NaN      NaN
2   comparison1     NaN      NaN     1.0    NaN      1.0
3   comparison2    100.0     NaN     1.0    NaN      1.0
4   comparison3     NaN      NaN     1.0   100.0     100.0
5   comparison4     NaN      NaN    100.0   NaN      NaN
```

The result should look like this:

```
     rule_id        51594   51668   51147   51182   51447
0   comparison1     1.0      1.0     NaN    NaN      NaN
1   last_comp       50.0     50.0    NaN    NaN      NaN
2   comparison1     NaN      NaN     1.0    NaN      1.0
3   comparison2     100      NaN     1.0    NaN      1.0
4   comparison3     NaN      NaN     1.0    100      25.0
5   comparison4     NaN      NaN     12.5   NaN      NaN
```

This is the code:

```
for key in df:
    for i, value in enumerate(df[key]):
        n = 1
        t = 100
        if value == t and i > 0 and df[key][i-n] == 1.0:
            df[key][i] = value/2  
            n = n+1
            t = t/2
    break
```

Basically what I did here is I declared 2 variables .The value of n as 1 and t as 100 and then used them in an if loop.

The result I am getting is:

```
    rule_id        51594    51668   51147   51182   51447
0   comparison1     1.0      1.0     NaN    NaN      NaN
1   last_comp       50.0     50.0    NaN    NaN      NaN
2   comparison1     NaN      NaN     1.0    NaN      1.0
3   comparison2    100.0     NaN     1.0    NaN      1.0
4   comparison3     NaN      NaN     1.0   100.0     50.0
5   comparison4     NaN      NaN     50.0   NaN      NaN
```

I don't know what the problem is. If you could help me resolve the issue , that would be great.

Comment: Does the data stop after `100` in each column, or does this need to be done multiple times for each column for every group of `1xN 100` you encounter

Comment: I have edited the question right now. I have written columns instead of rows. My apologies and to answer your question , the maximum score is 100 so you can say it stops at 100. The value of 100 should be changed only if the row above it has 1 otherwise not.

Comment: Yes , one column can have multiple values of 1 1 100 or 1 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazing question, took me a while to solve it, but I think the below is what you're after

```
def init(df):
    for title in list(df):
        column = df[title]
        the_last_value_was_a_one = False
        number_of_consecutive_ones = 1
        for i, value in enumerate(column):
            if value == 1:
                the_last_value_was_a_one = True
                number_of_consecutive_ones *= 2
            elif (value == 100) and (the_last_value_was_a_one == True):
                df.at[i, title] = 100/(number_of_consecutive_ones)
                the_last_value_was_a_one = False
                number_of_consecutive_ones = 1
            else:
                the_last_value_was_a_one = False
                number_of_consecutive_ones = 1
    return df


df = init(df)
```

Which returns:

```
     rule_id    51594   51668   51147   51182   51447
0   comparison1 1.0     1.0     NaN      NaN    NaN
1   last_comp   50.0    50.0    NaN      NaN    NaN
2   comparison1 NaN     NaN     1.0      NaN    1.0
3   comparison2 100.0   NaN     1.0      NaN    1.0
4   comparison3 NaN     NaN     1.0     100.0   25.0
5   comparison3 NaN     NaN     12.5    NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

I think do this for each column separately. Need to form groups for each column every time you encounter 100.

```
import pandas as pd

for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[col] = (df[col].groupby(df[col].eq(100).shift(1).fillna(0).cumsum())
                      .apply(lambda x: x.mask(x == 100, 100/(2**x.eq(1).sum()))))
```

#### Output:

```
       rule_id  51594  51668  51147  51182  51447
0  comparison1    1.0    1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
1    last_comp   50.0   50.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  comparison1    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    1.0
3  comparison2  100.0    NaN    1.0    NaN    1.0
4  comparison3    NaN    NaN    1.0  100.0   25.0
5  comparison4    NaN    NaN   12.5    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I have a large dataset. This is just a part of that data. I have around 1000s of columns , I can't do this for each and every column. Can you suggest something more feasible? I have also included the code in my question , basically what it does is it iterate through and check if the previous row's value is 1.0 when you encounter a 100.0 value. Can you make some alterations using that code?

Comment: @sagarkhanna then use RockHardRacoon's solution. It's surprisingly fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1": [1,1,100,1,1,100], 'col2': [1,1,100,1,1,100]})

# get list of columns (will be used later)
cols = df.columns

# create list of next division by 2 (will be used later)
original = 100
ll = []
for x in range(1, 20):
    ll.append(original)
    original /= 2

ll = list(zip([x for x in range(1, 20)], ll))

# create dictionary of indexes and divisions
dd = {x:y for x,y in ll}


for c in df.columns:
    df[f'{c}_next'] = df[c].shift(-1)

# main function get 1&100 pairs and replacing values
def compare_vals(row, cols):
    counter = 1
    for c in cols:
        if row[f'{c}_next'] == 100 and row[c] == 1:
            counter += 1

    for c in cols:
        if row[f'{c}_next'] == 100 and row[c] == 1:
            row[f'{c}_next'] = dd[counter]
    return row

df_new = df.apply(lambda row: compare_vals(row, cols), axis=1)

df_new = df_new[[x for x in df_new.columns if x not in cols]]
cols_new = {x: x.replace('_next', '') for x in df_new.columns}
df_new = df_new.rename(columns=cols_new)
df_new = df_new.shift(1)
df_new.iloc[0, :] = df.iloc[0,:]
```

OUTPUT

```
   col1  col2
0   1.0   1.0
1   1.0   1.0
2  25.0  25.0
3   1.0   1.0
4   1.0   1.0
5  25.0  25.0
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the result I want. I have edited my question to add how my code makes the result look.

Comment: Your result looks identical to mine. In the result where you are getting 50 , the value should be 25.

Comment: ah cool, i have not noticed you have had changed the rules. yeah, it is simple so just change the counter value to start from 1 and not 0.